# How do I extract the value of a 'Style'?

Tags: expression-manipulation, conversion, style

I have a Style displaying an underlying `Real` value. For example I might have

```
Style[NumberForm[10.01, {10, 2}], FontFamily -> "Academy Engraved LET", FontSize -> 50, FontColor -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0]]
```

or

```
Style[1201/100000, FontFamily -> "Charter", FontSize -> 20]
```

or potentially any other arbitrary `Style` expression representing a `Real`.

and I want to get the values `10.01` and `0.01201`, respectively.

Comment: It's probably best to try to avoid storing values together with wrappers like `Style`, `MatrixForm`, `NumberForm`, etc.  Apply the wrappers only before display, but not while doing computations.  We need to do the same when using `Dynamic`.  Of course this is not an answer, just a suggestion.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Good advice though. I worked myself into a corner.

Comment: `f[x_?NumericQ] := N @ x;  f[x_] := f @ First[x]` ?

Comment: @Kuba: Excellent! I tried just about every guess *close* to that, but never quite hit on the right formulation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
stripF = ToExpression[ToString[#, StandardForm]] &;

stripF /@ {Style[1201/100000, FontFamily -> "Charter",  FontSize -> 20], 
  Style[NumberForm[10.01, {10, 2}], FontFamily -> "Academy Engraved LET",
        FontSize -> 50, FontColor -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0]]}
(* {1201/100000, 10.01} *)
```

Also:

```
CalculateUtilities`StringUtilities`Private`stripformatting /@ 
 {Style[1201/100000, FontFamily -> "Charter", FontSize -> 20], 
  Style[NumberForm[10.01, {10, 2}], FontFamily -> "Academy Engraved LET",
        FontSize -> 50, FontColor -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0]]}
(* {1201/100000, 10.010} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may never know how many wrappers there are but those functions have this in common that first argument is what we only care about.

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := N @ x;  
f[x_] := f @ First[x]
```